# How to find layer dimensions in Gimp

Tags: gimp, psd

In Gimp, what is the easiest (fewest clicks/keyboard shortcut/setting change) way to find the dimensions of a given layer in a PSD file?

Is

> "Layers window"→<right click>→"Scale layer"

the only way?

Could the "Move tool" provide this info, or is there a setting that enables the display of this information by default?

Comment: `Scale layer` is the only way I am aware of. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm currently on ubuntu 11.10, but also use gimp in Win7

Comment: Is there a reason for using .psd with Gimp?

Comment: Yes. PSD is the file format that I am receiving images in. I don't have control over the format. However, I am guessing that PSD vs XCF makes little difference in regard to identifying layer dimensions at a glance; I could be wrong though.

Comment: Good question! Something like the Photoshop info panel would be helpful (although I find even that to be unintuitive sometimes).

Comment: I use `Layer > Layer Boundary Size`.

Comment: Does Layer->Layer boundary size do what you want?

Comment: This now has an answer [here, on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18057252/786559) -- Use the Status bar with %x, %y

Answer (score 0):

this plugin may be useful, it states that it shows a floating window with the active layer's dimensions: http://registry.gimp.org/node/26317